# Bluestacks, should I enable Virtualization?

Tags: bluestacks

Whilst downloading Bluestacks V4 it notifies the user to change the PC settings to enable CPU "Virtualization". I'd like to know if this is really necessary and whether it will have any side effects on my computer running on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualisation technology allows multiple workloads to share common resources on your computer. Basically, it allows your computer to run multiple tasks separate of each other, as if they were separate machines, which can be useful when using emulators and virtual machines.

It does not have any real impact on your computer and is not harmful to your computer, nor will it have any side effects or problems. Enabling it will allow BlueStacks to run more effectively and work better, which is why BlueStacks recommends you enable it. I know it works because I've used BlueStacks with and without Virtualisation technology, and the difference in performance is noticeable. It does help BlueStacks to run better.

I do recommend you enable it if you want the best experience in BlueStacks. Enabling it in the BIOS is pretty easy if you know how to navigate with arrow keys and know how to use the FN keys. I recommend you Google how to enable Virtualisation (which can also be known as VT-x and VT-i on Itanium processors) in the BIOS and follow the instructions on there.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualisation technology doesn't harm your computer. It is necessary if you want your emulator to run more effectively. Without activating it, your emulator won't work as effectively. You can turn it on; there will not any problems or side effects. You can activate Virtualisation in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

BlueStacks is known for its Android emulator.
As the CPU on an Android phone is different from that on the PC,
it needs to emulate it. This process is called
[x86 virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization)
and is by default disabled on many computer models.

Bluestacks asks to enable virtualization as described in the support article
[How can I enable virtualization (VT) on my PC](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003174386-How-can-I-enable-virtualization-VT-on-my-PC-#%E2%80%9C3%E2%80%9D).

The process is painful, since it needs to be done in the BIOS.
If Virtualization is not enabled, BlueStacks cannot do its work of emulating
a phone CPU.

Enabling Virtualization will not have any ill effects on the computer.
It may also speed up virtualization software such as VMware or Virtualbox.
Programs that don't emulate other hardware do not care if this is
enabled or not.

In short, it can only have beneficial effects, not negative ones.